# Modular Arithmetic Problem (Dividing by 3)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

If $p^3-q^5=(p+q)^2$ and $p \equiv q \;(\operatorname{mod} \,3)$ then why does $3 \nmid (p^3-q^5)?$

Here, $p, q >3$ and both are prime.

How to solve the question above?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that $p^3-q^5<p^3<p^5<(p+q)^5$. Therefore, the hypothesis never holds.

Comment: $p,q$ either $\equiv1$ or $\equiv 2\pmod{3}$

Answer (score 2):

If $p\equiv q \mod 3$ then $(p+q)^2\equiv (2q)^2 \equiv q^2 \neq 0\mod 3$.

Then, $p^3-q^5$ is not divisible by $3$

Comment: there was a mistake in the question , the power would be 2 instead of 5.

Comment: The hypothesis mentions $(p+q)^{\color{red}2}$.

Comment: The question changes!

Comment: Anyway, i edited.

Comment: $p,q$ are primes $>3$...

Comment: So they are. I expect conditions like that to be stated before the statements to prove and missed it.

Answer (score 0):

Noting Martín Vacas Vignolo's answer, we also have:

Suppose we have primes $p,q>3$ with $p\equiv q \bmod 3$.

Then $p^2\equiv 1$ and $p^3\equiv p\bmod 3$; similarly $q^5\equiv q \bmod 3$, so $p^3-q^5\equiv 0\bmod 3$.

But we know $(p+q)^2\equiv (2p)^2 \equiv 4\equiv 1 \bmod 3$. So the two quantities cannot be equal.